# Making Directories in SAS (Windows)

Tags: sas

I run some sas queries on a monthly basis and they export data to specific folders. Problem is I have to manually make these folders before I run the code so SAS wont error out.

Is there any way to automate this?

My folders have to be named in this fashion:

number of the Month - Name of the Month Year (12 - Dec 2011). I would also like to create a subfolder called Excel.

Also is there any way the month and number is populated automatically...so when I run this in January it changes to (1 - Jan 2012)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [X](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#win-cmd-x.htm) or [SYSTASK](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#win-stmt-systask.htm) commands can do this.

However, if you are in the Enterprise Guide environment (I don't believe) it is allowed by default in 9.2. I think 9.3 is going to allow it by default in the local environment ([SAS DUMMY blog)](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2011/09/01/xcmd-and-sas-9-3/)

Example:

```
options noxwait;

data _null_;
 month=strip(put(month(today()),2.));
 year=strip(put(year(today()),4.));
 monname=put(today(),monname3.);
 dir_name=month !! " - " !! monname !! " " !! year;
 call symputx('dir_name',dir_name);
run;
%put &dir_name;

x "cd D:\Data";
x "%str(mkdir %"&dir_name%")";
```

Another option is the [DCREATE](http://support.sas.com/onlinedoc/913/getDoc/en/lrdict.hlp/a002332693.htm) function

Example:

```
data _null_;
 month=month(today());
 year=year(today());

 dir_name=put(month,2.) !! " - " !! put(today(),monname3.) !! " " !! put(year,4.);
 NewDirectory=dcreate(dir_name,'D:\Data\');
run;
```

Comment: Thanks! As I understand.. this will make a directory called New_Dir in the Data Folder.... Is there any way for it to automatically pick up the current month number / month name and year? eg. (01 - Jan 2012)

Comment: Also, this only seems to work on local drives. How would I modify this so it works with network drives?

Comment: I updated my answer. If by "network drives" you mean mapped drives...then you should still be able to reference them the same way ( K:\ or X:\ )...if you want to do this on a server, post more info

Comment: For server drives, it's the same principle, eg. `mkdir "\\server\share\&dir_name."`

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy solution to create if not exist and use if exist. 
The code snippet is given below.

```
%Macro Verifica_Lib(Libreria,Ruta);
Data _Null_;
Call Symput('Destino',&Ruta||Compress('&Libreria'));
Run;
%Put &Destino;
%If (%SysFunc(LibRef(&Libreria))) Ne 0 %Then %Do;
%Put Verificando existencia de libreria;
%Put La libreira &Libreria No Existe;
%Put Se procederaa crearla;
Options DLCreateDir;
LibName &Libreria "&Destino";
%End;
%Else %Do;
%Put Verificando existencia de libreria;
%Put La libreira &Libreria existe;
%Put Se continuara el proceso;
%End;
%Error_Sas(Verificacion de Libreria local);
%MEnd Verifica_Lib;
```